# How to render another react component on a single button click? (Functional Component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am very new to React and I want to render another react component on a single click.
I have a component ListModules which has a button in it, now when I click the button another component  should get rendered. I have written the below code,
module is my state and has value from the backend.

```
    const addTimeline = () => {
      return <ColorsTimeline data={module} />
      }
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onClick={addTimeline}>DONE</button>
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
const[show,setShow]=useState(false);
return(
{show?<ColorsTimeline data={module} />:null}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onClick={()=>{setShow(true)}}>DONE</button>
)
```

---

**Edit:** if you want to hide the button once it gets clicked? Click the button, call another component and hide button! For example:

```
const [showButton,setShowButton]=useState(true);
return(
  {show?<ColorsTimeline data={module} />:null}
  {showButton?<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onClick={()=>{setShow(true);setShowButton(false)}}>DONE</button>:null}
)
```

or better do this:

```
return(
  {show?<ColorsTimeline data={module} />:null}
  {!show?<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onClick={()=>{setShow(true)}}>DONE</button>:null}
)
```